# Issues while verifying if the build was successful

Tags: iphone

I'm creating a build for distribution & it shows Build Succeeded message along with some warnings. I tried to verify if the build was successful by following the iphone developer user guide, according to which an  "embedded.mobileprovision” file should be created. 
Is it necessary that code should be free of warnings to get a successful build along with
 "embedded.mobileprovision” file?.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on kind of warning. Which warning do you mean?

My personal rule - no warnings at all. I'm passing compiler switch to treat warnings as errors in release builds.

Comment: Xcode4 - select your project, target, build settings and scroll down to LLVM GCC 4.2 - Warnings and enable Treat Warnings as Errors (command line switch -Werror). If you do not use LLVM GCC 4.2 or Xcode4, just search in build settings for Treat Warnings as Errors.